# How to define seeder that creates m2m relationship on Voyager Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, seeding, eloquent-relationship, voyager

A resource has name
and a relationship of m2m with terms
For instance a resource might be a book, and a term might be an author.
This is part of a seeder that im creating to automate the bread creation on my project.

the tables are resource, terms, and resource_term
resource_term has id, resource_id, and term_id

```
$resDataType = DataType::where('slug', 'resources')->firstOrFail();
        $dataRow = $this->dataRow($resDataType, 'term_belongstomany_resource_relationship');
        if (!$dataRow->exists) {
            $dataRow->fill([
                'type'         => 'relationship',
                'display_name' => 'Término',
                'required'     => 1,
                'browse'       => 1,
                'read'         => 1,
                'edit'         => 1,
                'add'          => 1,
                'delete'       => 0,
                'details'      => '{"model":App\\BizneUp\\Domain\\Model\\Term,"table":"terms","type":"belongsToMany","column":"term_id","key":"id","label":"name","pivot_table":"resource_term","pivot":"0"}',
                'order'        => 12,
            ])->save();
        }
```

The error it throws at me when i open the bread is this:

array_diff_key(): Argument #1 is not an array (View: /home/rush4u/projects/bizneup/bizneup_backend/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/tools/bread/relationship-partial.blade.php) (View: /home/rush4u/projects/bizneup/bizneup_backend/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/tools/bread/relationship-partial.blade.php)

On this line of the voyager template:
    $adv_details = 
    array_diff_key(json_decode(json_encode($relationshipDetails), true), $relationshipKeyArray);

If anyone has done these types of things give me a hand please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dataRow = $this->dataRow($userDataType, 'resource_belongstomany_term_relationship');
        if (!$dataRow->exists) {
            $dataRow->fill([
                'type'         => 'relationship',
                'display_name' => 'Términos',
                'required'     => 0,
                'browse'       => 1,
                'read'         => 1,
                'edit'         => 1,
                'add'          => 1,
                'delete'       => 0,
                'details'      => [
                    'model'       => Term::class,
                    'table'       => 'terms',
                    'type'        => 'belongsToMany',
                    'column'      => 'id',
                    'key'         => 'id',
                    'label'       => 'name',
                    'pivot_table' => 'resource_term',
                    'pivot'       => '1',
                    'taggable'    => '0',
                ],
                'order'        => 12,
            ])->save();
        }
```

Details explained for M2m relationships

```
'details' => [
    'model'       => Term::class, //model class
    'table'       => 'terms', // table you are related to
    'type'        => 'belongsToMany', // rel name
    'column'      => 'id', // id of main side entity of rel
    'key'         => 'id', // id of related side entity
    'label'       => 'name', // field to act as toString when displaying the relation on read, browse, etc.
    'pivot_table' => 'resource_term', // m2m table name
    'pivot'       => '1',
    'taggable'    => '0',
];
```

Hope this helps people facing the same problem (setting up voyager relationships manually)

cheers